# Cancel Order from magento 2 frontend?

Tags: magento2, orders

Cancel Order from website frontend by customer in magento 2 enterprise edition.

Is there anyway to do without extensions?

Answer (score 2):

**[EDIT]** Please careful when allowing the customer to cancel order on the Front page. I only want to give a hint for this issue.

In Magento 2 CE, we can use `\Magento\Sales\Api\OrderManagementInterface` to cancel the order.

**app/code/Vendor/Module/Controller/Order/Cancel.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Order;

use Magento\Sales\Controller\OrderInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Sales\Controller\AbstractController\OrderLoaderInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;

class Cancel extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action implements OrderInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderManagementInterface
     */
    protected $_order;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Controller\AbstractController\OrderLoaderInterface
     */
    protected $orderLoader;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $registry;

    /**
     * Cancel constructor.
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderManagementInterface $orderManagementInterface
     * @param Context $context
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderManagementInterface $orderManagementInterface,
        OrderLoaderInterface $orderLoader,
        Registry $registry,
        Context $context
    )
    {
        $this->_order = $orderManagementInterface;
        $this->orderLoader = $orderLoader;
        $this->registry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $result = $this->orderLoader->load($this->_request);
        if ($result instanceof \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface) {
            return $result;
        }
        $order = $this->registry->registry('current_order');
        //$orderId = 1;
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        try {
            $this->_order->cancel($order->getId());

        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
            if ($this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Checkout\Model\Session')->getUseNotice(true)) {
                $this->messageManager->addNotice($e->getMessage());
            } else {
                $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
            }
        }
        return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/history');
    }
}
```

Re-use the sale route:

**app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/routes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="sales">
            <module name="Vendor_Module"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

In your browser, we can call directly: `http://{base_url}/sales/order/cancel/order_id/76/`

**Remember that we need to use `Magento\Sales\Controller\AbstractController\OrderLoaderInterface` for checking the authorization.**

Comment: What is the redirect URL for cancel button in My Order page.

Comment: I'm not sure about your idea! However, the redirect URL : `return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/history');`.

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh I have created the file as per your answer but I am getting page not found once i hit the url with order id, can you please help me on this.

Comment: You try to create the new route?

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh I have created `app/code/Vendor/Module/Controller/Order/Cancel.php` and `app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/routes.xml`  files what else I have to do? Sorry I am new to magento.

Comment: You know how to create a new module in Magento 2? http://inchoo.net/magento-2/how-to-create-a-basic-module-in-magento-2/

Comment: I've created a module to fully implement the controller Khao has given here: https://github.com/lingwooc/cancel-magento2 (credit to Khao given). I've addressed why it doesn't solve many problems here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/135281

Answer (score 0):

Cancel order from frontend can be easily achieved with few easy steps:-

**Step1:-** Change the sales_order_history XML file to change the default order history template(we will add cancel link). **Path**:- view/frontend/layout/sales_order_history.xml.

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
<referenceBlock name="sales.order.history">
<action method="setTemplate">
<argument name="template" xsi:type="string">vendor_name_CancelOrder::cancel.phtml</argument>
</action>
</referenceBlock>
</body>
</page>
```

**Step 2:-** Add the cancel link on the template. **Path**:view/frontend/templates/cancel.phtml

```
<?php $_orders = $block->getOrders(); ?>
<?php $block->getChildHtml('info'); ?>
<?php if ($_orders && count($_orders)): ?>
    <div class="table-wrapper orders-history">
        <table class="data table table-order-items history" id="my-orders-table">
            <caption class="table-caption"><?php echo __('Orders') ?></caption>
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col" class="col id"><?php echo __('Order #') ?></th>
                <th scope="col" class="col date"><?php echo __('Date') ?></th>
                <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('extra.column.header'); ?>
                <th scope="col" class="col shipping"><?php echo __('Ship To') ?></th>
                <th scope="col" class="col total"><?php echo __('Order Total') ?></th>
                <th scope="col" class="col status"><?php echo __('Status') ?></th>
                <th scope="col" class="col actions">&nbsp;</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php foreach ($_orders as $_order): ?>
                <tr>
                    <td data-th="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Order #')) ?>" class="col id"><?php / @escapeNotVerified / echo $_order->getRealOrderId() ?></td>
                    <td data-th="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Date')) ?>" class="col date"><?php / @escapeNotVerified / echo $block->formatDate($_order->getCreatedAt()) ?></td>
                    <?php $extra = $block->getChildBlock('extra.container'); ?>
                    <?php if ($extra): ?>
                        <?php $extra->setOrder($_order); ?>
                        <?php echo $extra->getChildHtml() ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <td data-th="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Ship To')) ?>" class="col shipping"><?php echo $_order->getShippingAddress() ? $block->escapeHtml($_order->getShippingAddress()->getName()) : '&nbsp;' ?></td>
                    <td data-th="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Order Total')) ?>" class="col total"><?php echo $_order->formatPrice($_order->getGrandTotal()) ?></td>
                    <td data-th="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Status')) ?>" class="col status"><?php echo $_order->getStatusLabel() ?></td>
                    <td data-th="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Actions')) ?>" class="col actions">
                        <a href="<?php echo $block->getViewUrl($_order) ?>" class="action view">
                            <span><?php echo __('View Order') ?></span>
                        </a>
                        <?php if ($this->helper('Magento\Sales\Helper\Reorder')->canReorder($_order->getEntityId())) : ?>
                            <a href="#" data-post='<?php
                            echo $this->helper(\Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper::class)
                                ->getPostData($block->getReorderUrl($_order))
                            ?>' class="action order">
                                <span><?php echo __('Reorder') ?></span>
                            </a>
                        <?php endif ?>
                        <a href="sales/order/cancel/id/<?php echo $_order->getRealOrderId() ?>">
        <span><?php echo __('Cancel') ?></span>
    </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <?php if ($block->getPagerHtml()): ?>
        <div class="order-products-toolbar toolbar bottom"><?php echo $block->getPagerHtml(); ?></div>
    <?php endif ?>
<?php else: ?>
    <div class="message info empty"><span><?php / @escapeNotVerified / echo __('You have placed no orders.'); ?></span></div>
<?php endif ?>
```

**Step 3:-** Finally create a controller that fetches the order then checks whether it is cancelable or not and if yes then cancel's the order by id.
**Path:-** Controller/Order/Cancel.php

```
$orderId = $this->_request->getParam('id'); $order = $this->orderRepository->get($orderId);
if ($order->canCancel()) {
$this->order->cancel($order->getId());
}
```