# Magento 2 : Is it possible to add order cancellation functionality in frontend?

Tags: magento2, sales-order, order-status, edit-order

I want to give the order cancellation functionality in frontend to user in case of order not shipped. 
What would be the step to achieve this functionality ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/133003/cancel-order-from-magento-2-frontend

Answer (score 6):

This is more complicated than it sounds.

Cancellation while pending is easy. The method is described in [Cancel Order from magento 2 frontend?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/133003) and I've implemented it in a module with the template tweaks needed (and confirmation dialogues).

https://github.com/lingwooc/cancel-magento2

You should note this only works for **pending** orders. Most orders (especially online payments) won't go into pending, they will go into **processing**. For online payments this means the money will have been taken and will need to be refunded. Magento doesn't allow cancellation at this stage, only shipping or refund. I would think carefully about whether you want your customers to be able to generate a refund automatically. There is the potential you may ship refunded goods if you don't have a robust process. I would implement this as a refund request which should generate a support ticket. The module above has the templates/layouts that you would need to change to add such a button.

This chart shows the status change flow of a mangeto2 order.

[image: Magento2 order status flowchart]

Source question: [New order status staying "pending" instead of processing in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/163414/new-order-status-staying-pending-instead-of-processing-in-magento-2)

Source: https://www.mexbs.com/magento-blog/magento-order-statestatus-flow

Answer (score 2):

You must create an extension:

1. First of all you have to overwrite the customer account page layout in order to introduce the control (button) that links to a functionality.
2. The button you added should link to a controller that does the job.
3. Eventually you will need to add some blocks to render any output/intermediate interaction.