# New order status staying "pending" instead of processing in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, orders, payment, order-status

We are using the Multisafepay payment methods and all our incoming orders get the status pending in our Magento2 webshop.

Is there a setting we have to put in to get the orders to processing? It also looks like I can only choose by Multisafepay between pending and pending payment.

Answer (score 9):

We can assign the New Order Status. I will give some basic info:

**Login to Magento Admin > STORES > Configuration > SALES > Payment Methods > Choose the Payment**, you will see the config for the New Order Status:

[image]

Create the New Order status: **STORES > Order Status**, we can create a new status for the custom payment. And then, **we need to assign this status to the new state**.

In short, one state can have many statuses. You can define any status, for your understanding. While a state can be a specific case, Magento need to handle it internally.

1) For the offline payments, for example, after placing order successfully, the order has the `new` state, however, it can have a new status if we assign a new status to this state. The order will change the state and status to `processing` after creating invoice or shipment.

2) For the online payments, they're more complicated. The payment has some basic methods:

- Authorized: A payment authorization is a hold of funds on your account, which is not an actual charge. The order can be assigned the `new` state. Read more here: https://support.turo.com/hc/en-us/articles/203991180-What-is-a-payment-authorization
- Capture: After capturing payment, our order is paid , so, the order can change the state and status to processing. We can manually make the request capture by creating online invoice in Admin. Or, process Capture after Authorized. programmatically.
- Canceled: Canceled the order. The order can change the state and status to cancel.
- Void: Void can be the same with Canceled case.
- Refund: We can make a full or partial refund, online or offline refund. A credit memo will be created if choosing offline refund.

In your case, I'm not sure about this payment, however, we can process Capture Payment after Authorization payment. The order can change the state and status to processing.

THE ORDER STATE & STATUS FLOW CHART:

https://www.mexbs.com/magento-blog/magento-order-statestatus-flow

[image]

Comment: The image is nice. I couldn't find this scenario:
 New / Pending > (Invoice) > Processing / Processing > (Partial Payment)? A customer placed an order, I invoiced it, haven't shipped it yet, he emailed me asking he forgot to use a new offer discount, so I applied partial refund, the order status is Complete now. Is this expected? How do I make it Processing again. It doesn't make sense to Ship a complete order.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of Khoa TruongDinh is theoretically working, however, there is an Magento Ticket regarding an issue, where this property is ignored: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5860

According to the comments, it should be fixed in Magento 2.3 and it was backported to 2.1 as well. I can confirm that it's not working in Magento 2.2.6