# Magento 2: How to change order status of Pending to Payment Received?

Tags: magento2, event-observer, sales-order, admin-panel, order-status

Hi i'm new at magento 2 and i want to simulate the order status change of Pending to Payment Received. How can i do this? And which event can i observe to when the order status get changed to Payment Received?

Comment: check this link --- https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/163521/85907

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i don't think it solves my problem. I just want to observe when the status changes to Payment Received and i also want to simulate this status change. If there is any method to do this on the admin area or something too.

Comment: customer added online pay order directly goes to invoice section.i mean order adding credit card or other

Comment: I'm in a homologation environment using sample data to test my store, so I still don't have a functional payment method.